# Netsuite saved search extract the words before Pipe symbol

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I need to extract the words before pipe symbol(|) from a memo field value in Netsuite and and the Id after Pipe from the value in memo field in netsuite

for example :
memo field has **Andreas Riepen | ipi_1NjTgoRW1iGQmhiTKDKi5vI3 | | Scandinavian Airlines | Purchase**

I need to extract **Andreas Riepen**  and **ipi_1NjTgoRW1iGQmhiTKDKi5vI3** from the memo fields into two separate results

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.